# JQuery Hover State On Timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if it's possible with jQuery to activate a:hover for 2 seconds at the start page then turn off. I'm very new to javascript not sure if this is outside of what javascript should be used for?

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: Do you mean you want to listen to a 'hover' event, but only for two seconds?

Or do you want to change the visual styling of some element for two seconds, and then have that style go away?

Comment: Hello Hunterloftis, sorry should have been more clear. Yes I would like to change the visual styling for a small amount of time at the page load then go away (return to normal), thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: You can't trigger .hover (I've tried) so you have to add a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add a class to your CSS selector, then add/remove that class with jQuery:

**CSS:**

```css
#element:hover, #element.mock-hover {
    /* styles go here... */
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $el = $('#element');

    $el.addClass('mock-hover');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $el.removeClass('mock-hover');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rg4B/

Comment: Perhaps the correct CSS is `#element.mock-hover:hover { ...`?